# Use .format with string dictionary

Tags: python

I want to use my dictionary parameter in my string
Here is my dictionary

```
a = {"first_name": "ABC", "last_name": "PQR"}
```

Following statement gives correct output

```
"{first_name}{last_name}".format(**a)
```

But I want following output

```
"{ Hello {first_name} {last_name}.}".format(**a)
>>> '{ Hello ABC PQR.}'
```

It gives keyerror

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-84fc42fb81f2> in <module>()
----> 1 "{ Hello {first_name} {last_name}.}".format(**a)

KeyError: ' Hello {first_name} {last_name}'
```

Comment: Placeholders use `{...}`. Don't use those for literal text.

Comment: Do you want it to print the first and last { } to the screen? (Is your desired output "{ Hello ABC PQR.}"?)

Comment: @phogl yes I want this output "{ Hello ABC PQR.}"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter literal braces by doubling them:

```
>>> a = {"first_name": "ABC", "last_name": "PQR"}
>>> "{{ Hello {first_name} {last_name}.}}".format(**a)
'{ Hello ABC PQR.}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include `Hello` in the formatting:

```
"{{Hello {first_name} {last_name}.}}".format(**a)

# "{Hello ABC PQR.}"
```

Use double curly braces `{{}}` to escape `{}`

Comment: Heh, misread the question.

Comment: Actually I want "{Hello ABC PQR.}" , That is my requirement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP's question was not so clear, I have apparently made the same misinterpretation

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is

```
"{{ Hello {first_name} {last_name}.}}".format(**a)
```